# CLLocationManagerDelegate, when will the method be invoke: locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

in CLLocationManagerDelegate, when will the method be invoke: locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:

could you explain more detail, if possible could you explain with example? thanks very much

1. if my current location is changing(eg, I am on a train), does this method be invoked? if yes, how many times or how frequently it is be invoked?
2. if I stay at one place and not move, does this method be invoked? if yes, how many times or how frequently it is be invoked?

Comment: implement this and see for yourself!!! btw it is called in both stationary and moving modes. Also depends on what distanceFilter you set. It may be called multiple times with varying location accuracy for same point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is called whenever your iOS device has moved past the distance filter you have set. For example if you set it to

```
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
```

The method will be called every time the device is moved.

A code example of this would be finding the coordinates then assigning those values to labels

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
altitudeLabel.text = @"0 ft";
ftOrM = YES;
// Note: we are using Core Location directly to get the user location updates.
// We could normally use MKMapView's user location update delegation but this does not work in
// the background.  Plus we want "kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation" which gives us a better accuracy.
//
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
self.locationManager.delegate = self; // Tells the location manager to send updates to this object
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:   (CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { 
tLatitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude]; 
tLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
/*  the following returns 0 */
float distanceMeters;
float distanceFeet;
if (ftOrM == YES) {
    distanceMeters = newLocation.altitude;
    distanceFeet = distanceMeters * 3.2808399;
    tAltitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f ft",    distanceFeet];
     altitudeLabel.text = tAltitude;
}
else {
tAltitude  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f m",    newLocation.altitude];
NSLog(@"Altitude:");
NSLog(@"%@", tAltitude);
altitudeLabel.text = tAltitude;
NSLog(@"Altitude:");
NSLog(@"%@", tAltitude);
}
//[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Might be Overkill but I had trouble understanding as well, so I figured might as well to make sure the info is out there

Answer (score 1):

For the first one this method will invoked, and the frequency depends on the speed.

And if don't change your location then this method will not invoked.

And how much time your location is changing this method will call.